# Focuslab Multi Environment Config upload preferences issue

Tags: file-uploads, focus-lab-master-config

I'm having an issue with my upload directories. I converted an existing site to use the FocusLab config set up and everything is working fine. However I've just noticed that in the CP thumbnails are missing from all entries and on the front end new images are not being displayed.

I ftp'd into the server and in my directories I can see the images but they've all been renamed so that they are directorynamefilenam.jpg

i.e. house.jpg inside directory general is now named generalhouse.jpg.

Not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

The relevant code from config.master.php is below

```
/**
 * Custom upload directory paths
 * 
 * The array keys must match the ID from exp_upload_prefs
 */
 $env_config['upload_preferences'] = array(
     1 => array(
         'name'        => 'Home Page Slideshow',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/home_slideshow',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/home_slideshow/'
     ),
     2 => array(
         'name'        => 'Portfolio Logos',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/portfolio',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/portfolio/'
     ),
     3 => array(
         'name'        => 'Team Photos',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/team',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/team/'
     ),
     4 => array(
         'name'        => 'News Images',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/news',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/news/'
     ),
     4 => array(
         'name'        => 'General',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/general',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/general/'
     )
 );
```

If I synchronize a directory I get the following errors:

> generalColor_Block_Icon_with_i.jpg: invalid_filename
>
> generalPetArmor-Dog.png: invalid_filename

This is error is on all images on all directories.

Comment: Double check that $images_path and $images_url are correct (I usually use $base_path and $base_url instead) Also, add a slash to the end of $images_path/s e.g `'server_path' => $images_path . '/home_slideshow/',`

Comment: Nate - I did what you said and it worked, but I think that Stephen's answer below would cover it. Anyhow all good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the trailing slash for the 'server_path' also.

```
/**
 * Custom upload directory paths
 * 
 * The array keys must match the ID from exp_upload_prefs
 */
 $env_config['upload_preferences'] = array(
     1 => array(
         'name'        => 'Home Page Slideshow',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/home_slideshow/',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/home_slideshow/'
     ),
     2 => array(
         'name'        => 'Portfolio Logos',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/portfolio/',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/portfolio/'
     ),
     3 => array(
         'name'        => 'Team Photos',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/team/',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/team/'
     ),
     4 => array(
         'name'        => 'News Images',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/news/',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/news/'
     ),
     4 => array(
         'name'        => 'General',
         'server_path' => $images_path . '/general/',
         'url'         => $images_url  . '/general/'
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem. I was able to fix it by updating the EE install from 2.3.1 (I think) to 2.8.1.